# How to hack into the Unix Kernel to remove the Exponential Backoff from TCP?

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp, linux-kernel

I came up with the idea that if we remove the exponential backoff time from TCP, this will improve the performance of the TCP throughput. I came across a paper also, which said how to do it. Just google "remove tcp exponential back off time" and you will get it. But, I am not able to understand how to get into the UNIX kernel and hack it inorder to change the TCP functioning. Please, if anyone can help me out then it would be simply great.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd be better off using a network simulator to try out this hypothesis, like ns-3, and it's TCP congestion control implementations (TCP Vegas, TCP Reno, TCP New Reno..) :)

Comment: Ya, I am using a ns-2 simulator, but, I don't want to do it that way. I want to improve it through the kernel parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that were true, why would the exponential backoff be in there? Do you really think the guys who developed and evolved TCP added something just to make performance worse? And then, what, all the different operating systems implementation people added it without thinking?

Removing the exponential backoff will increase the packet loss rate (because congestion backoff won't be as rapid) and increase the latency (because the queues at each interface on the path will tend to be deeper). These two effects are multiplicative -- increased latency makes increased packet loss more damaging. The cumulative effects would be disastrous to throughput.

Linux permits a module to implement the TCP congestion control algorithm. So you can tweak it however you want. Have a look in the `net/ipv4` directory of the Linux kernel source, files like `tcp_hybla.c` and `tcp_veno.c`.

Comment: You are abs right in thinking, but, I am conducting this experiment between 2 nodes, where I know there will be no congestion it just that I am creating a lossy link between the 2 nodes. So, I want to remove the exponential back off time so that TCP drops packets only due to lossy link not due to congestion.

Comment: By default Unix uses which TCP control mechanism??.

Comment: You still need exponential backoff. Otherwise, the queues will be deep rather than shallow and the time to figure out that a packet has been dropped will be higher, meaning the packet loss will do more damage to throughput. What you probably want is `Veno`. It is designed to determine if packet loss is due to congestion or random and adjust accordingly without forming deep queues. It is standard on Linux (the code is in the kernel and most distributions provide the module), you just need to load the module and select it. Linux uses [Cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUBIC_TCP) by default.

Comment: How do I implement this veno at the Unix kernel level???.. I mean are there any commands to get this done on my node???

Comment: `/sbin/modprobe tcp_veno && /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=veno`

Comment: it's not really true that queues will be deeper (I suppose the average queue depth might). Overall, TCP will by design fill the bottleneck queue, since it won't back-off until a queue is full and causes a packet loss

Comment: @Arvid: It's not that simple because the packet rate is not constant and the queuing behavior is often specifically designed to trigger packet loss before the queues are full to preserve latency for other users.

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~akm175/docs/extr.pdf) points out that exponential backoff is unnecessary as long as packet conservation principle is followed. After an evaluation of the paper I think the implementation is good for lossy links but not for congested links.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential backoff (for CSMA/CD) is done in the physical layer (implemented as hardware usually), where you handle the signalling.

And even if it is tunable, it is likely done at the firmware level, not kernel source.

But another area of exponential backoff is in router - this is perhaps where you can tune it.